How to set a DocumentGroup's toolbar background to visible?
When adding toolbar items to a view presented in a DocumentGroup, the toolbarBackground and toolbarBackgroundVisibility view modifiers do not seem to affect the DocumentGroup's own NavigationBar:
struct ToolbarTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: ToolbarTestDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @Binding var document: ToolbarTestDocument
    @State var showInspector: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $document.text)
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    showInspector.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Label("Show inspector", systemImage: "sidebar.trailing")
                }
            }
            .toolbarBackground(.bar, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackgroundVisibility(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .inspector(isPresented: $showInspector) {
                Text("Inspector")
            }
    }
}


Alternatively, I tried adding a NavigationStack inside the DocumentGroup:
struct ToolbarTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: ToolbarTestDocument()) { file in
            NavigationStack {
                ContentView(document: file.$document)
            }
        }
    }
}

This way, the background view modifiers work, but I get a double navigation bar (the DocumentGroup's bar and the NavigationStack's bar on top of each other):

How to set a DocumentGroup's toolbar background to visible, either without introducing a NavigationStack, or making sure that inserting the NavigationStack does not result in a double NavigationBar?
